# Android HttpURLConnection with fiddler: IOException: socket is closed

Tags: android, https, proxy, httpurlconnection, fiddler

I set up Fiddler2 for Android emulator, it works, I can see the HTTPS traffic through Android browser, but I cannot connect to HTTPS server with my code using HttpsURLConnection:

```
    // use Fiddler's proxy:
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("172.16.4.20", 8888));
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url)
            .openConnection(proxy);

    connection.setRequestMethod(method);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
```

I got:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

In Fiddler I can see the first request (I removed the host address)

```
CONNECT [address]:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: [address] 
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; Android SDK built for x86 Build/IMM76D)
Connection: Keep-Alive

After the client received notice of the established CONNECT, it failed to send any data.
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 12:32:18.567
Connection: close
```

The above request response pair is like any other Android browser HTTPS connection establishment.

After that I cannot send my POST request (because I got the SocketException). Without proxy it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the client is closing the connection because it's not satisfied with Fiddler's HTTPS decryption certificate. Have you configured the device to trust the FiddlerRoot.cer certificate file? Have you attached an event handler to your HttpsURLConnection to accept Fiddler's self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes, I added FiddlerRoot.cer and I trust in all certificates. Like I said in Android browser everything is fine with HTTPS sites, and I can see the traffic in Fiddler.

Comment: That suggests that the apps don't inherit the certificate trust from the browser. Have you attached an event handler to your HttpsURLConnection to accept Fiddler's self-signed certificate?

Comment: I came across the exact same issue. I have installed FiddlerRoot.cer on my device, like Attila said I can sniff https traffic from Android browser and Chrome. What do you mean "attached an event handler to your HttpsURLConnection to accept Fillder's self-signed certificate"? I have implemented a dummy TrustManager which does nothing and use it as a part of SSLSocketFactory. But it's not working around. I'm still getting SocketException saying "socket is closed"

Comment: @TakashiOguma: You should probably open a new question that includes the code you're using, as well as repro information about versions and whether your dummy TrustManager is getting called, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on my iphone. 
What I did was visiting this url 
 ht_tp(remove the under score)://(replace_with_the_ip_of_the_host_where_fiddler_is_running):8888

from your mobile device (in your case your emulated Android device)
And then you would be displayed a webpage as described on this link
[click this](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForiOS)

You need to install the certificate. After that, you will be displayed with the response in fiddler.

Enjoy!

Comment: This does not work from the application, that will only help to capture the browser traffic

Comment: It is working for me at least from physical device with the Http proxy set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that the app uses Certificate pinning. Instead of trusting any certificate in the "trust store" of the device, it is configured to trust only a specific certificate(signed by the server).

So when Fiddler presents its own certificate, client raises error.

More details :https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29988/what-is-certificate-pinning